# How to Return the texts from selenium?

Tags: python, text, return, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

**Work on a program and want to get content written inside the dialog box
Use Selenium chromedriver Python, I want to get the text written by the user
Use the experiment to get the text text written into the text box of the Google search engine

```
search = browser.find_element_by_name ('q')
search.send_keys ("google search through python")
# t = browser.find_element_by_name ('q').text
#print (t) //Output: '' //string empty 
#print (search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)): Output: none
# search.send_keys (Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
# search.send_keys (Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
#t = search.send_keys (Keys.RETURN, 'v')
#print (t) //Output: None**
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to figure out what exactly you are asking for. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to ask good questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, the *text* of an element is (roughly speaking) the content found between its opening and closing tags:

```
<p>This is the text of a paragraph element.<p>
```

An `<input>` element, however, doesn’t have any inner content. Instead, its value is stored in its *`value` attribute*:

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="google search through python" />
```

This is why `.text` always returns `None`: no inner content means no text. Instead, you need to use `.get_attribute("value")`:

```py
search = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("google search through python")
print search.get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: Thank you so much
Another question please ..
How can I control the settings
I want to save records, additions, settings and more
Each time the program is restarted, only the default settings will be restored and all additions and records will be deleted ! !

Comment: @RASHASANYOUR Please post this as another question on Stack Overflow, being sure to follow the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.